# How to typecheck nested params in React/React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes

I have an array of objects named `data.messages` that I want to typecheck in a component called `Chat':

```js
Chat.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.shape({
        messages: PropTypes.arrayOf({
            createdAt: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            image: PropTypes.string,
            isTyping: PropTypes.bool,
            text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            user: PropTypes.shape({
                firstName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
                id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            })
        })
    })
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error message:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Property `data.messages` of component
>   `Chat` has invalid PropType notation inside arrayOf.

When I try to do the following instead:

```js
Chat.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.shape({
        messages: PropTypes.array({
            createdAt: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            image: PropTypes.string,
            isTyping: PropTypes.bool,
            text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            user: PropTypes.shape({
                firstName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
                id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            })
        })
    })
}
```

I get the following error message:

> Warning: Failed propType: Calling PropTypes validators directly is not
>   supported by the `prop-types` package. Use
>   `PropTypes.checkPropTypes()` to call them.

The property types inside the objects accurately matches the ones specified above so there's no mistake on that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Chat.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.shape({
        messages: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
            createdAt: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            image: PropTypes.string,
            isTyping: PropTypes.bool,
            text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            user: PropTypes.shape({
                firstName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
                id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            })
        }))
    })
}
```

`PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({...}))` is what you were missing

Comment: I still get the second error message which is `Failed propType: Calling PropTypes validators directly is not supported by the prop-types package.`

Comment: Where is that error message coming from? Are you trying to check the proptypes directly somewhere/somehow?

Comment: The only time it shows is when `PropTypes.array` is there for the `messages` param. I've tried commenting out everything else

Comment: Hmmmm.  Does it work with `PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({...}))` ?